# How to show more destinations in web than mobile with Go Router and StatefulShellRoute.indexedStack

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation, flutter-go-router

With go router we can use **StatefulShellRoute.indexedStack** to defines a list of navigation route in our go router settings :

```
StatefulShellRoute.indexedStack(
          branches: myBranchesList,
          builder: (context, state, navigationShell) {
            return ScaffoldWithNestedNavigation(
                navigationShell: navigationShell);
          }),
```

Indexed stack take the number of item in the list to handle the selected item, but what if we want more item depending on the plateform ?

Since we cannot use a condition in the branch, what would be the best approach to have differents number of branches depending on if we are on the web or the mobile ?

Answer (score 0):

```
List<GlobalKey<NavigatorState>> not_web_use_list =[GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'shell_1'),GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'shell_2')...];

List<GlobalKey<NavigatorState>> web_use_list =[GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'shell_web_1'),GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'shell_web_2')...];

List<GlobalKey<NavigatorState>> all_use_list =[...not_web_use_list , if(kisweb)...web_use_list ];
```

Comment: Please add a description of the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<GlobalKey<NavigatorState>> shell_list =[
GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'shell_1'),
if(kisweb)GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'shell_2_web'),
GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'shell_3'),
if(kisweb)GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'shell_4_web'),
GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'shell_5'),
if(kisweb)GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'shell_6_web'),
...
];
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: Please add a description of the code.